# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.tools.spi.IManagedTypeProvider

Tags: java, netbeans, eclipselink, netbeans-8

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.0.1 (on Win XP). I have recently upgraded EclipseLink from 2.5.2 to [2.6.0](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/). The update was propagated successfully to required places. There is no server related issue. It works just fine with Java EE applications.

I have placed the following JAR files under `${NetBeansHome}/java/modules/ext/eclipselink`.

- eclipselink.jar
- javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070.jar
- org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen_2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070.jar

As they had been before the update was made.

I do not get IDE's intelligence anywhere by means of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> after these changes were made.  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> causes the following exception to be thrown.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.tools.spi.IManagedTypeProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:222)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.tools.spi.IManagedTypeProvider starting from ModuleCL@cc3bba[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence] with possible defining loaders [ModuleCL@1d2f158[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.eclipselink]] and declared parents [org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@d84586, ModuleCL@e6aaa7[org.netbeans.modules.queries], ModuleCL@af4256[org.netbeans.api.java], ModuleCL@1d96b0c[org.netbeans.modules.xml.lexer], ModuleCL@2c0dbb[org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion], ModuleCL@92f2e7[org.openide.actions], ModuleCL@85b121[org.netbeans.modules.xml.text], ModuleCL@131e02f[org.netbeans.modules.java.sourceui], ModuleCL@4079d6[org.netbeans.core.multiview], ModuleCL@b3a92a[org.netbeans.modules.dbapi], ...37 more]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:224)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/jpql/tools/spi/IManagedTypeProvider
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence.editor.completion.JPACodeCompletionProvider$JPACodeCompletionQuery.initResolvers(JPACodeCompletionProvider.java:127)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence.editor.completion.JPACodeCompletionProvider$JPACodeCompletionQuery.<init>(JPACodeCompletionProvider.java:120)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence.editor.completion.JPACodeCompletionProvider.createTask(JPACodeCompletionProvider.java:96)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.completionQuery(CompletionImpl.java:721)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.showCompletion(CompletionImpl.java:925)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.access$2400(CompletionImpl.java:111)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl$CompletionShowAction.actionPerformed(CompletionImpl.java:1613)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.dispatchKeyEvent(CompletionImpl.java:644)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.keyPressed(CompletionImpl.java:404)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:250)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:249)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6483)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2829)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6302)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4752)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Do the above-mentioned JAR files not contain the class `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.tools.spi.IManagedTypeProvider`? Are some other JAR files required to be added to `${NetBeansHome}/java/modules/ext/eclipselink` with respect to the new version of EclipseLink? What is the fix in essence?

---

Some bug reports are found but they were already fixed in respective versions.

- https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=226296

---

**EDIT:**

The class `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.tools.spi.IManagedTypeProvider` is available in `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070.jar` but based on the IDE's log, it appears that it still refers to an old JAR file somewhere `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar`. This did not happen during previous updates to EclipseLink in the past.

```
INFO [org.netbeans.JarClassLoader]: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar does not exist, # of retries 0
INFO [org.netbeans.JarClassLoader]: file C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\java\modules\ext\eclipselink exists. # of retries 0
INFO [org.netbeans.JarClassLoader]: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\java\modules\ext\eclipselink is directory and contains: [eclipselink.jar, javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar, org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070.jar, org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen_2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070.jar]
INFO [org.netbeans.JarClassLoader]: Cannot open C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:145)
    at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader$JarSource$1.call(JarClassLoader.java:524)
Caused: java.util.zip.ZipException: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader$JarSource$1.call(JarClassLoader.java:526)
    at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader$JarSource$1.call(JarClassLoader.java:515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader$JarSource.getJarFile(JarClassLoader.java:550)
[catch] at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader$JarSource.resource(JarClassLoader.java:591)
    at org.netbeans.Archive.getData(Archive.java:212)
    at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader$JarSource.readClass(JarClassLoader.java:577)
    at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader$Source.getClassData(JarClassLoader.java:374)
    at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader.doLoadClass(JarClassLoader.java:221)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.selfLoadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:259)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:187)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence.editor.completion.JPACodeCompletionProvider$JPACodeCompletionQuery.initResolvers(JPACodeCompletionProvider.java:127)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence.editor.completion.JPACodeCompletionProvider$JPACodeCompletionQuery.<init>(JPACodeCompletionProvider.java:120)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence.editor.completion.JPACodeCompletionProvider.createTask(JPACodeCompletionProvider.java:96)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.completionQuery(CompletionImpl.java:721)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.showCompletion(CompletionImpl.java:925)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.access$2400(CompletionImpl.java:111)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl$CompletionShowAction.actionPerformed(CompletionImpl.java:1613)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.dispatchKeyEvent(CompletionImpl.java:644)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.keyPressed(CompletionImpl.java:404)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:250)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:249)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6483)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2829)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6302)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4752)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
INFO [org.netbeans.JarClassLoader]: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\java\modules\ext\eclipselink\org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd.jar does not exist, # of retries -1
INFO [org.netbeans.JarClassLoader]: file C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\java\modules\ext\eclipselink exists. # of retries -1
INFO [org.netbeans.JarClassLoader]: C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\java\modules\ext\eclipselink is directory and contains: [eclipselink.jar, javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar, org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070.jar, org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen_2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070.jar]
SEVERE [global]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.tools.spi.IManagedTypeProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:222)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.tools.spi.IManagedTypeProvider starting from ModuleCL@e4568e[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence] with possible defining loaders [ModuleCL@27dbf9[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.eclipselink]] and declared parents [ModuleCL@1fa7a03[org.netbeans.modules.projectapi], ModuleCL@3538b6[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.core.utilities], ModuleCL@1df7c09[org.netbeans.modules.xml.catalog], org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@d84586, ModuleCL@12640e6[org.netbeans.modules.db], ModuleCL@54c934[org.netbeans.modules.lexer], ModuleCL@18d7b5f[org.netbeans.api.xml], ModuleCL@ab06aa[org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib], ModuleCL@11a7cb[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistenceapi], ModuleCL@b42ace[org.netbeans.modules.xml.text], ...37 more]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:224)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/jpql/tools/spi/IManagedTypeProvider
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence.editor.completion.JPACodeCompletionProvider$JPACodeCompletionQuery.initResolvers(JPACodeCompletionProvider.java:127)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence.editor.completion.JPACodeCompletionProvider$JPACodeCompletionQuery.<init>(JPACodeCompletionProvider.java:120)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence.editor.completion.JPACodeCompletionProvider.createTask(JPACodeCompletionProvider.java:96)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.completionQuery(CompletionImpl.java:721)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.showCompletion(CompletionImpl.java:925)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.access$2400(CompletionImpl.java:111)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl$CompletionShowAction.actionPerformed(CompletionImpl.java:1613)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.dispatchKeyEvent(CompletionImpl.java:644)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.keyPressed(CompletionImpl.java:404)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:250)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:249)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6483)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2829)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6302)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4752)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in / marked with the position attribute: [org-netbeans-modules-editor-java-JavaBracesMatcher.shadow], but some are: [org-netbeans-modules-editor-bracesmatching-LegacyEssMatcher.instance, org-netbeans-modules-editor-bracesmatching-DefaultMatcher.instance]
SEVERE [global]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.tools.spi.IManagedTypeProvider
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:222)
Caused: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.tools.spi.IManagedTypeProvider starting from ModuleCL@e4568e[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence] with possible defining loaders [ModuleCL@27dbf9[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.eclipselink]] and declared parents [ModuleCL@1fa7a03[org.netbeans.modules.projectapi], ModuleCL@3538b6[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.core.utilities], ModuleCL@1df7c09[org.netbeans.modules.xml.catalog], org.netbeans.MainImpl$BootClassLoader@d84586, ModuleCL@12640e6[org.netbeans.modules.db], ModuleCL@54c934[org.netbeans.modules.lexer], ModuleCL@18d7b5f[org.netbeans.api.xml], ModuleCL@ab06aa[org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib], ModuleCL@11a7cb[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistenceapi], ModuleCL@b42ace[org.netbeans.modules.xml.text], ...37 more]
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:224)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/persistence/jpa/jpql/tools/spi/IManagedTypeProvider
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence.editor.completion.JPACodeCompletionProvider$JPACodeCompletionQuery.initResolvers(JPACodeCompletionProvider.java:127)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence.editor.completion.JPACodeCompletionProvider$JPACodeCompletionQuery.<init>(JPACodeCompletionProvider.java:120)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.persistence.editor.completion.JPACodeCompletionProvider.createTask(JPACodeCompletionProvider.java:96)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.completionQuery(CompletionImpl.java:721)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.showCompletion(CompletionImpl.java:925)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.access$2400(CompletionImpl.java:111)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl$CompletionShowAction.actionPerformed(CompletionImpl.java:1613)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.dispatchKeyEvent(CompletionImpl.java:644)
    at org.netbeans.modules.editor.completion.CompletionImpl.keyPressed(CompletionImpl.java:404)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:250)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(AWTEventMulticaster.java:249)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6483)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2829)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6302)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4752)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
[catch] at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0):

`org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.tools.spi.IManagedTypeProvider` is in
`org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql_2.6.1.qualifier.jar` in my build (2.6.1 branch from git) but you already have it there. Maybe try to create new library in NetBeans containing all those JARs and use it instead this one.

Unfortunately I'm leaving on vacation now but I can have a look at this closer next week. We may update EclipseLink to 2.6.0 in master branch of NetBeans.

Comment: The class `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql.tools.spi.IManagedTypeProvider` is available in the said JAR file as you said but NetBeans still appears to use the old name of the JAR file somewhere. It is a NetBeans own module/repository which is used for the IDE's own purposes only. Does adding those JAR files collectively as a library as usual will then work?

Comment: NetBeans has it's own hard-coded EclipseLink library so replacing just files wont's help much. That's why I was suggesting you to create your own library with all current JARs. Give it a try and let me know. I'm back so I'll talk to local NB development team about EclipseLink update in NB ASAP. They are going to release 8.1 soon so dev build shall be quite stable now.

Comment: Thank you. This did not happen, when I replaced an EclipseLink version from 2.5.1 to 2.5.2 in the past and even before that.

Comment: "*They are going to release 8.1 **soon***". On [*NetBeans Release Roadmap*](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/roadmap.html), the release period of NetBeans 8.1 is October 2015 i.e. it will be released at least 6 months later. Is it going to be released before October 2015?

Comment: No. NB guys just asked me to fix all P1/P2 bugs in GlassFish plugin what means that they want to get development branch really stable. :) But I also have some bad news, EclipseLink 6.0 update in NB shall wait a bit, I have much more important tasks on EclipseLink itself and NB guys don't have time to do that too. :(